# How to type in password for multiple windows?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, gnome3, gnome-terminal, vagrant

I have a script that starts my vagrant machine, opens up multiple terminals and connects to the vagrant machine via ssh in every newly opened terminal. My problem is that I need about five terminals, and I don't want to type in the password for each terminal manually. Is there a way to get prompted for the password only once in the main terminal, and use the same password for the ssh command?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/kkri/public_html/freitag/vagrant
vagrant up
for run in $(seq 1 $1)
 do
  gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=dark -e "ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222" --$
 done
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=git          
clear
echo "~~~ Have fun! ~~~"
```

Comment: Why don't you set up passwordless access and use ssh keys instead? That's both more secure and simpler. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: As terdon said, you can use a private/public SSH key; this will also make actions like `scp` more comfortable without compromising security. The following link provides a HowTo that should be applicable to your remote system, too. If you trust your environment enough (firewalled intranet) you can even generate a key without passphrase. https://www.linode.com/docs/security/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh

Comment: There is such as `cssh` and `pssh` (Cluster SSH respectively Parallel SSH)

Comment: As an aside: Why use `ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222` rather than `vagrant ssh`? The latter is better as it will correct the port if you have more then one vagrant box running.

Comment: Use `vagrant ssh`!!

Comment: @terdon ironically Vagrant is **required** to be setup with not only paswordless login but paswordless sudo to allow Vagrant to automatically provision the machine (set up networking, shares etc) - this is a major case of XY.

Comment: If I use vagrant ssh it will attempt to connect to my default vagrant machine, and the ssh part is in a different script that I want to be able to run from any folder.

Comment: @Chris so really that's your question, no? If your script cds into the vagrant machine's directory (which it does) then it should work fine.

Comment: It would work if I would use it as a separate script, but if I call the script inside a script and do the cd command it will end up in the wrong place.

Comment: No it won't, unless your wrapper script is also using cd (which should be avoid in scripts for this reason). If you are required to cd at all you should cd back when done with `cd -` or better yet use `pushd` and `popd` to change directory. It seems to me you are trying to work around managing your current working directory rather than just managing it correctly.

Comment: +1 for clusterssh - though it is an extremely dangerous, macho, better-know-your-heaven-well tool ;)

Comment: @Chris Do you really need five separate SSH connections? Did you look at GNU Screen or other terminal multiplexer like `tmux`? I'm curious as to why they wouldn't work out in your case.

Comment: I don't really necessarily need five connections, I just want to run multiple background processes like a solr server that keep me from doing anything else in the terminal, and I don't know tmux at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general (ignoring vagrant or other system-specific details) your best bet is to set up authentication with SSH keys, and run `ssh-agent`. Then open the ssh sessions with something like:

```
# load the key to the agent with a 10 s timeout
# this asks for the key passphrase
ssh-add -t10  ~/.ssh/id_rsa  
for x in 1 2 3 ; do 
    ssh .... 
done
```

Or, if you can't use keys, you could rig something up with `sshpass`.

```
read -p "Enter password: " -s SSHPASS ; echo
for x in 1 2 3 ; do 
    sshpass -e ssh ...
done
unset SSHPASS
```

Though with the terminal in the middle, this would leave the password set in the terminal's environment. To work around that, you could save the password temporarily in a file:

```
read -p "Enter password: " -s SSHPASS ; echo
PWFILE=~/.ssh/secret_password
cat <<< "$SSHPASS" > "$PWFILE"
unset SSHPASS
for x in 1 2 3 ; do 
    sshpass -f "$PWFILE" ssh ...
done
shred --remove "$PWFILE"
```

This still isn't optimal since there's a chance the password hits the disk, so keys would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using vagrant you can simply run `vagrant ssh` to ssh to the box without having to enter a password. This will also handle port collisions if you have more then one vagrant box running and various other things.

Alternatively you can use tmux instead of gnome-terminals and make use of its synchronize-panes feature:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux_name="vagrantssh-$BASHPID"
tmux new -s $tmux_name -d
for run in $(seq 1 $1); do
    tmux splitw -t $tmux_name -v "ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222"
    tmux select-layout -t $tmux_name tiled
done
tmux kill-pane -t 1
tmux set-window-option -t $tmux_name synchronize-panes on
tmux select-layout -t $tmux_name tiled
tmux new-window -t $tmux_name
tmux kill-window
tmux attach -t $tmux_name
```

This will launch tmux and run the ssh command in the number of panes that you have specified, with all the panes synchronized (tmux forwards keys to all the panes). Once you have done what you want to all the panes you can press `ctrl+b` then `:set synchronize-panes off` to turn off the input sync. This can be bound to a key for convenience.

Comment: `tmux` seems like a good idea, however, I'm wondering why you would want multiple SSH connections instead of simply one connection and running `tmux` on the vagrant machine?

Comment: That also works, assuming you have it installed inside vagrant - not always the case. You also get to use your tmux config if you have modified it at all without needing to copy it to every vagrant box you provision. This script was also adapted from a script I used to tmux to multiple different hosts so is more flexible in that regard.

Comment: Also, you can modify the script to start some panes not inside vagrant and have them all managed by one tmux session.

Answer (score 3):

The approach would be to use key authentication, it is safer, and solves the authentication problem.

Just generate a key pair with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And copy/paste the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to the `~/.authorized_keys` in the server machine. If the file doesn't exist, check the permissions to user only.

If you use multiples terminals I recommend `terminator`, it actually solves this kind of problem with *broadcast keybord to all terminals* features